# Header is not bold in edit preview

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, markdown-preview

See edit here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/12229/edit

[image: bold?]

Then see the final result: [How did Douglas Adams choose the Ultimate Question?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12229/3383)

[image: yes bold!]

What is going on here?

Comment: +1 for your last freehand circle, the emphasis looks terrible :o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix will be in the next production build.